# UIActivityIndicator while loading data into UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UITableView which loads its data from the web. It takes a while to load this data and therefore I would like an acitivity indicator to animate while the data is loading. I am doing the following in my attempt to make this work:

1) In viewDidLoad I add an observer to listen to when the data loading is done and after that I call loadDataFromWeb

2) loadDataFromWeb creates the activity indicator, adds it as a subview to self.view and then it loads the data. At last it posts a notification (the one that viewDidLoad observes) to indicate that the loading process is done.

3) Finally, when the observer catches the post from loadDataFromWeb, it calls removeLoadingScreen to remove the indicator.

Pretty obvious I am not seeing my indicator view. If I comment out the line that removes the indicator, it stays on the screen when everything is loaded. I am aware that I'm probably messing around with which methods are called when in the process, and this is where I need help.

I should mention that the whole purpose is that instead of the user's looking at a screen on which nothing is happening (while the data loads), I want a activity indicator to show up to indicate that there's something going on here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are doing your network communications outside the main thread? Looks like your letting the main thread do the download, which is a no-no :]

Comment: Nils Munch you are totally right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Muncken have a look at this MBProgresHUD project, this will help you a lot to do a downloading progress in background (secondary thread not main thread) and shows a activity indicator over you view -

https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

Comment: saadnib I will take a look at this and then return. Thanks you!

Comment: That looks great, saadnib. However I am strugling a bit with how to implement it into my project. The threads are fired in an IBAction in the demo project. Where should I fire them?

Comment: Okay I have moved a bit forward here, but it seems that there's something I'm missing. The loader shows up as it should and I can see, using NSLog, that the loader-method is run properly, but it seems that no data loads. This is my viewDidLoad: http://pastebin.com/LZkjRjdG

Comment: your viewDidLoad looks right. Can you please post your fuction code in which you are loading data through HUD?

Comment: Aha, I also have to load the data through HUD some how? I wasn't aware of that. Anyway, here's the loadData function: http://pastebin.com/LR8rmC7B